# Tomcat 7 error, At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I've working on Intellij IDEA 14.1.4 with Spring and MVC.
After I run my project I have that error message:

```
At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

I've search on the internet and I've found more solution for my problem but no one of them don't works for me :(

1. On of them was: "Add this line on logging.properties in \conf\"

   org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.level = FINE

and I do that but nothing happen.

http://i.imgur.com/RwWc7RC.png

2. And the second answer was: "Add this line on catalina.properties in \conf\"

   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.jarsToSkip=

but again, nothing happen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhBoR.png

So can anyone save me? :D
Thx in advance

Comment: Did you restart the tomcat?

Comment: That's not an error, is just a warning, it says that you can specify some jars for them to be skipped when Tomcat searchs for TLD files, that way Tomcat can start faster

Comment: Morgano is correct, that ain't an error, Check your localhost log if your app is not starting. In Intellij Idea, click on run on bottom, it will open a sort of a window, in that there should be Tomcat Localhost log, you will see error there.

Comment: @morgano - Although, I would agree this is more of a warning, it can also help to skip them to improve performance as indicated by the message.